# Vue build for specific mode is ignored if using lerna run

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, lerna

So I have a vue project with this script in the package.json:

```
"build-test": "vue-cli-service build --mode test"
```

In the project, I have .env and .env.test files.
Now, everything used to work fine, when I build using the "build-test",
it results in the .env.test configuration [as it supposed to](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

Now, the problem started when I added lerna to the project.
I tried to add a script in the main package.json which basically calls:

```
lerna run build-test --scope @company/web-app --include-dependencies
```

But when I do it, it results in getting the configuration from the default .env file and not the .env.test file.

If I run the command "build-test" from the web-app folder, it executes as it should, with the right .env file used.
Anyone has idea what is the problem by any chance?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
lerna run build-test --scope @company/web-app
```

lerna automatically loads `.env` file from `@company/web-app`, which is messing up with `process.env` keys

- keys from `.env` will override `.env.test`
- when you don't run build with lerna, `.env.test` keys properly overrides `.env` keys

SOLUTION:

add flag `--load-env-files=false`

```
lerna run build-test --scope @company/web-app --load-env-files=false
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/run?activeTab=readme#--load-env-files